# Anaconda navigator will not open, but doesn't throw an error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, windows-10

Anaconda navigator suddenly won't open. I don't get an error or anything, it starts initializing and then disappears... nothing opens, no error. I can still launch Jupyter Notebook separately, but am also now unable to read in data directly from a URL. The kernel "dies" and prompts a restart. I have read through similar questions, tried updating conda, tried re-installing the navigator.... nothing works! HELP!!

Also if this makes a difference I am using Windows 10

Comment: Can't help further without relevant stack error traces. You may just want to uninstall and do a fresh install of conda; that should normally fix it

Comment: thats the thing, when anaconda won't open theres literally no error. it just doesn't open. i did try uninstalling and re-installing fresh with no change! I mentioned the URL issue in case it is somehow related and the error sayd "Ther kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Comment: There could be multitude of reasons for the cause of that error. Have you tried searching that error on google and implementing possible solutions?